# How many zeros of $z^{17}+z-1$ lie in the region $|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, holomorphic-functions, rouches-theorem

General problem:

**Conjecture** (B. Galo and Jack D'Aurizio) Let $p$ be a prime number then the number of zeros of $z^{p}+z-1$ that lie in the region $|z|<1$ is:

1)  $⌊\frac{p}{3}⌋-2$ (where $⌊*⌋$ is the lower integer function). If $ p≡5 (mod6)$ but $p\neq 5$.

2) $⌊\frac{p}{3}⌋$. If this result is odd and $p\not\equiv 5 (mod6)$

3) $⌊\frac{p}{3}⌋+1$. If $⌊\frac{p}{3}⌋$ is even number.

I have to thanks Jack D'Aurizo for the "review" of my attempt and for sketching the proof.

Comment: It is very simple to notice that if $|z|$ is small, $|z^p|$ is even smaller and $|1-z|\geq 1-\varepsilon$, hence $z^p\neq 1-z$.

Comment: Additionally $z^p+z-1$ has a real root in $(0,1)$ that is close to $1-\frac{1}{p}$ by Newton's method. All the roots of $f(z)$ lie outside the disk centered at the origin with such radius.

Comment: Moreover, if $p\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ there are two roots **on** the boundary of the unit disk, at $\exp\left(\pm\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$.

Comment: I agree with you Jack, It has a real root in (0,1) that is close to $1-\frac{1}{p}$ Newton's method. But I didn't get for another p-1 roots. My original problem is another prime number greater than 2000, because of that I was thinking about "is It possible to generalize this?"

Comment: What was your answer/solution to *how many zeroes of $z^{17}+z-1$ lie in the region $|z|<1$*?

Comment: I was trying to understand the behavior of zeros of this polynomial when I change p, just for fun. But I don't know how can I do this for p=17. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Yeap! I've changed it above!  Thanks

Comment: There are $5$ roots of $f(z)=z^{17}+z-1$ in the region $|z|<1$ by a numerical approximation of the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=0.999}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz$. $2$ roots lie on the boundary, $10$ roots outside the unit disk.

Comment: So, your idea is to use Argument principle and numerical approximation to solve this integral... Is it possible to do just analytically?

Comment: I was thinking about as f(z) has a real root that lies in the region |z|<1, then we can call this root of $\alpha$. Then, $f(z)=(z-\alpha)(z^{16}+...+\frac{1}{\alpha})$... call this new poly. $g(z)=(z^{16}+...+\frac{1}{\alpha})$ and look at its zeros.. something like that...

Comment: I am going to post a convincing geometric argument for my previous $\frac{p}{3}$ conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

If $p\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ the polynomial $z^p+z-1$ has exactly two roots on the unit circle, at $\exp\left(\pm\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$. Conversely, if $z^p+z-1$ has a root on the unit circle such root has to lie at the intersection of the sets $|z|=1$ and $|1-z|=1$, so $p\not\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ grants that $z^p+z-1$ has no root on the unit circle. By a numerical approximation of the integral
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1-\varepsilon}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz $$
for $f(z)=z^p+z-1$ it is not difficult to arrive at the following conjecture:

> **Conj**. About $\frac{p}{3}$ roots of the polynomial $z^p+z-1$ lie in the region $|z|<1$.

Here it comes a convincing geometric argument for proving such a conjecture. The number of roots of $f(z)$ in the region $|z|\leq 1$ is given by the [topological degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_degree_theory)/winding number around the origin of the curve

$$\gamma(\theta) = \left( \cos(p\theta)+\cos(\theta)-1,\sin(p\theta)+\sin(\theta)\right) $$
that is a generalized [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve)/ [epitrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid).
 For $p=17$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, for instance, it has the following structure:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

hence it is essentially given by a circle with unit radius that is rotating around the point $z=-1$ in seventeen steps. By trivial trigonometry about one third of such circles actually enclose the origin, and that leads to the $\frac{p}{3}$ mentioned before. By studying the behaviour of $\gamma(\theta)$ as $\theta$ travels on intervals with length $\frac{2\pi}{p}$, and by noticing that the number of roots of $z^p+z-1$ in $|z|<1$ is clearly odd, we have that:

> **Theo**. If $p\geq 11$ is a prime of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$, there are $2k+1$ roots of $q(z)=z^p+z-1$ in the region $|z|<1$. There are two roots of $q(z)$ on the unit circle, at $z=\exp\left(\pm\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$, iff $p=6k+5$.

Comment: You mean, lower integer of $|\frac{p}{3}|$ with that p=17 implies 5 roots in the region $|z|<1$?

Comment: @BelmiroGalo: exactly!

Comment: p=2 it's false... It can be true for p>2. I will think about it cause I've never seen that Lissajous curve...

Comment: @BelmiroGalo: the above argument works only if $p$ is large enough, $p\geq 11$. The remaining cases are simple to study by hand.

Comment: Jack, I guess I've found one mistake. You said when p=5 we have exactly two roots on the unit circle... Remember that no matter who p is we always know that there exists one real root in (0,1), another roots are complex conjugates. We must have a odd number of zeros in $|z|<1$, so my new conjecture is "the lower integer of $\left\lfloor\frac{p}{3}\right\rfloor$ is the number of roots of the polynomial $z^p+z−1$ lie in the region $|z|<1$ if this number is odd. Otherwise, It will be the greatest integer function of $\left\lceil \frac{p}{3} \right\rceil $.

Comment: It seems that it is working for whole primes now... if p=2 then 1 root. If p=3 then 1 root. If p=5 then 1 root. If p=7 then 3 roots, when p=11, $p≡5(mod 6)$ we know that we have 2 roots on the boundary as you said before $exp(±\pi i3)$ then we need to fix the conjecture more one time...

Comment: There is nothing to fix in the above argument: as soon as p is large enough, there are about p/3 roots inside the unit disk. If p=6k+5, two roots are on the boundary of the unit disk. The cases for small ps can be dealt by hand.

Comment: Do you agree with the new conjecture that I wrote on the top?

Comment: @BelmiroGalo: absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to apply the bilinear transformation $z = (1+x)/(1-x)$, then use Routh-Hurwitz. The calculation should not be too difficult since most of the coefficients are missing.

Comment: Many coefficients are missing in $f(z)$, but they are not missing anymore when you perform such substitution!

Comment: Additionally, the case $p=6k+5$ is critical because it involves two roots having modulus exactly $1$.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it helped much cause  they aren't missing anymore when you perform such substitution as Jack said before...

Answer (score 0):

**Visualiztion**

Start with
$$
f(z) = z^{17}+z-1
$$
The Re and Im components are shown next.

[image: all]

The $0$ contours, the line where
$$
\color{blue}{\text{Re } f= 0}, \qquad \color{red}{\text{Im } f= 0}
$$
are shown below against the unit circle. The roots where $f(z)=0$ are where the blue and red contours intersect. We see six roots within the unit disk.

[image: zero]

**Observation**

While using the argument principle, a pattern emerges.

Given
$$
 g(k,z) = z^{k} - z + 1
$$
compute the series expansion for
$$
 \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
The expansion coefficients are
$$
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
 k & const & w^1 & w^2 & w^3 & w^4 & w^5 & w^6 & w^7 & w^8 & w^9  & w^{10}\\\hline
 2 & -1 &  1 &  2 & \dots \\
 3 & -1 & -1 &  2 &  3 &  4 & \dots \\
 4 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  3 &  4 &  5 & 6 & \dots \\
 5 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  4 &  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \dots \\
 6 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \dots \\
 7 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \dots \\
\end{array}
$$